# Is it possible to update a ViewBag variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, viewbag

Can a viewbag variable be incremented using javascript method on a page? I have the following attempt:

```
function ConfirmFriend(friendID, addOrDecline) {

      alert(addOrDecline);

      if (parseInt(@ViewBag.ActualFriendCount) == 0 && addOrDecline == "add")
      {             
          alert("THIS IS A FIRST ADD");
          @{
              int test = Convert.ToUInt32(@ViewBag.ActualFriendCount);
              test++;
              @ViewBag.ActualFriendCount == test;
          }
      }

    var userID = '@ViewBag.UserID';

    var postData = {
        'userID': userID,
        'userFriendID': friendID,
        'addOrDelete': addOrDecline
    };

    $.post('/User/Show/', postData, function (data) {
    });

    document.getElementById("HiddenPendingFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'none';

    if (addOrDecline == 'add') {
        document.getElementById("HiddenAcceptedFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("HiddenDeclinedFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

Comment: viewbag is used for passing value from controller to view.you can assign and increment that value.what is the purpose

Comment: ViewBag is a server object, javascript runs on client. They cannot work together that directly. If you need to notify server about some changes on client, you need to send a request to do so

Comment: its not two way binding !

Comment: Cheers for the feedback guys have now attempted to get the value through an $.ajax POST.